# passing arguments to segments in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular , i would like to know is there a way to pass arguments from one segment to another.

```
<div ng-class="{active: ('s3' | routeSegmentStartsWith)}">
    <a href="#{{'s3' | routeSegmentUrl}}" > </a>
</div>
```

Route

```
.when('/section3/grid1', 's3.grid1')
    .segment('s3', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/sales.html',
        controller:'salesController'
    })
```